# Javascript - Calling Hash values through regex derived keys

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the code as follows:

```
  var str =
  `<doc>
        <a href="#h-1">
        <a href="#h-2">
        <a href="#h-3">
  </doc>
  <doc>
        <a href="#h-9">
  </doc>`

  var veg_anchor_map = new Object();
  veg_anchor_map['h-1'] = 'cabbage';
  veg_anchor_map['h-2'] = 'potato';
  veg_anchor_map['h-3'] = 'carrot';


  var href_regex = /<a href="#(.*?)"/g;
  str = str.replace(href_regex, veg_anchor_map['$1']);
  console.log(str);
```

I'm trying to replace all href links in my str variable to this syntax:

```
  //example:
  <doc>
        cabbage>;
        potato>;
        carrot>;
   </doc>
```

but every time I try to call the call the groupings in my regex statement it states, that it's undefined, can anybody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.replace()` function with callback function as a second argument:

```
...
var href_regex = /<a href="#(.*?)"/g;
str = str.replace(href_regex, function ($m0, $m1) {
    return veg_anchor_map[$m1] || $m0;
});
console.log(str); // <doc>cabbage>potato>carrot></doc><doc><a href="#h-9"></doc>
```

- `veg_anchor_map[$m1] || $m0` will return a replacement value from the `veg_anchor_map` object, otherwise(if not found) - returns the current match string